# Concurrent Bluetooth A2DP and RFCOMM communication

Tags: android, bluetooth

I would like to know whether it is possible to do A2DP streaming and RFCOMM to the same Bluetooth device concurrently. Would opening a socket for RFCOMM communication cause the A2DP stream to drop? Any known issues in this usage assuming it is possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible.
Opening the stream will not cause any issue on the A2DP, but depending on the implementation pushing a lot of data on the RFCOMM while A2DP is also streaming might cause some gaps in the streaming due to bandwidth constraints

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else finds this question and is looking for an answer. I'm doing this, on my Galaxy Nexus the audio streaming performs consistently but I see a drop in the data rate on my RFCOMM socket. I don't have exact numbers with me. But performance definitely dips when playing audio over A2DP, and then recovers after stopping A2DP. This is for serial communication at 115200 bps.

I should also add that this was done with Android 4.3 which uses a new bluetooth stack that is not BlueZ